# Create json file from input matrix by grouping rows

Tags: python, json, dictionary, transpose

Given the matrix below, I'd like to create and json output that will iterate through the matrix rows and append items (col 1) if the group (col2) repeats:

```
  matrix = [ 
        ['JAN', '1', 'abc'], 
        ['FEB', '7', 'xyz'], 
        ['FEB', '4', 'abc'], 
        ['MAR', '3', 'xyz'], 
        ['DEC','12', 'xyz']
      ]
```

how can be the a output/JSON file created:

```
{
     "month": ["JAN","FEB","FEB","MAR","DEC"],
     "items": [
        { "group":"abc",
         "data":[1,4]
        },
        { "group":"xyz",
         "data":[7,3,12]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I've tried transposed matrix/column and construct a dictionary where I append items in a for loop, but I am missing something and it's getting messy. it should be a simple way.

Comment: You could show some effort to solve the problem. Show what have you tried.

Comment: Does the JSON file need to be neat, pretty, spaced, indented?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This program:

```
from itertools import groupby
import json
matrix = [
    ['JAN',  '1', 'abc'],
    ['FEB',  '7', 'xyz'],
    ['FEB',  '4', 'abc'],
    ['MAR',  '3', 'xyz'],
    ['DEC', '12', 'xyz']
]
months = [x[0] for x in matrix]
items = [[x[2], int(x[1])] for x in matrix]
items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[0])
items = groupby(items, lambda x: x[0])
items = [{"group": k, "data": [x[1] for x in g]} for k, g in items]
result = {
    "month": months,
    "items": items
}
print (json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))
```

produces this output:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "data": [
                1,
                4
            ],
            "group": "abc"
        },
        {
            "data": [
                7,
                3,
                12
            ],
            "group": "xyz"
        }
    ],
    "month": [
        "JAN",
        "FEB",
        "FEB",
        "MAR",
        "DEC"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, your solution is great, although it is not the desired output. **Note** that the order is changed, for instance instead of " *data":[7,3,12]* it returns * "data":[3,7,12]* how could the order be respected?

Comment: @Algina, You can achieve that result by adding a `key` parameter to the `sorted()` call, like so: `items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: x[0])`

Comment: @Rob, this solve one problem but creates another, 
it changes the sorted items from: *items= [['abc', 1], ['abc', 4], ['xyz', 3], ['xyz', 7], ['xyz', 12]]* to: *items= [['abc', 1], ['xyz', 7], ['abc', 4], ['xyz', 3], ['xyz', 12]]*  What means that the final JSON won't be the desired. the sorted items should be: `items= [['abc', 1], ['abc', 4], ['xyz', 7], ['xyz', 3], ['xyz', 12]]`

Comment: @Algina, I don't understand your comment. The change I suggested does not produce the incorrect result you mention. I have updated my answer with suggested change and the resulting output.

Comment: @Rob, sorry for my mistake, indeed your solution by adding key on the sort function works fine! I had a type on items variable what lead to wrong output. Very nice and elegant solution! Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's probably best to use the `json` module but you can you standard file writing after a cast:

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as data:
    data.write(str(my_dict))
```

Comment: This doesn't group the data into groups as the OP requested. The OP doesn't just want to write the data in JSON format.

Comment: What do you mean groups? The OP said that he had already gotten the data in a dictionary format. All that's left is to cast and write.

Comment: "I've **tried** transposed matrix/column and construct a dictionary where I append items in a for loop, but I am missing something and it's getting messy."